# How to Implement and using nextTokenPage using Using GTLRYoutube iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-data-api

so I have a question how to use & implement nextPageToken Using GTLRYoutube in iOS Objective c which the example result is here :
( https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list ) and set the maxResults to "10" and the "nextPageToken will generate it".

**btw my flow to get the :**

1. ChannelID
2. and getting PlaylistID -> to get PlaylistItems
3. and VideoID one by one

and the code like this : 
1.

```
- (void)fetchChannelResource {

GTLRYouTubeQuery_ChannelsList *query =
[GTLRYouTubeQuery_ChannelsList queryWithPart:@"snippet,contentDetails"];
query.mine = true;

[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}
```

and execute query :

```
- (void)displayResultWithTicket:(GTLRServiceTicket *)ticket
         finishedWithObject:(GTLRYouTube_ChannelListResponse *)channels
                      error:(NSError *)error {
if (error == nil) {
    NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    if (channels.items.count > 0) {
        self.youtubeChannelDataArray = channels.items;
        [output appendString:@"Channel information:\n"];
        for (GTLRYouTube_Channel *channel in channels) {
            NSString *title = channel.snippet.title;
            NSString *description = channel.snippet.description;
            NSNumber *viewCount = channel.statistics.viewCount;
            [output appendFormat:@"Title: %@\nDescription: %@\nViewCount: %@\n", title, description, viewCount];
            NSString *uploadID = channel.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
            self.youtubeUploadID = uploadID;
        }

        //CALL fetchPlaylistItemResource
        [self fetchPlaylistItemResource];

    } else {
        [output appendString:@"Channel not found."];
    }
    //        self.output.text = output;
} else {
    //        [self showAlert:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription];
}
}
```

all the data saved in NSArray and NSMutableDictionary.

and in other viewController, i need to display them all.. but the problem is how to implement with nextPageToken which is will display 5 items resultPerPage ??

because when I use this "GTLRYoutube", looks like we don't need to make a new model, just use the model from GTLRYoutube, besides that also didn't make mapping and access the youtube API in the Datamanager.m

anyone have a suggestion or advise ???

thanks before!